# Set maximum line count for WrapPanel containing text and images?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wrappanel

Is there a way to set a maximum line count for a WPF WrapPanel?  The goal would be to max out at 2 lines and add an ellipses if the content would normally wrap to a 3rd line.  The trick is that the content is dynamic and not known at compile time.

[image]

Comment: That looks more like a FlowDocument than a WrapPanel.

Comment: Restructuring as a FlowDocument would be fine, but would yield the same question of knowing the resulting line count so an ellipses could be used.

Comment: Must you use a `WrapPanel`? Why not a `TextBlock`?

Comment: Textblock with Inline content is fine, but would there be a way to know when the 2nd line ends so an ellipses can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `TextBlock` like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource someText}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="10"/>
```

Comment: This overlooks both key points of the question title - showing images and having a maximum line count.

Comment: You can set ItemHeight and ItemWidth properties of the WrapPanel